# Should not acknowledging a message cause it to be redelivered to the Kafka consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ibm-mq, spring-cloud-stream

I am running a Spring Cloud Stream application where I read transactions from a Kafka topic, process the transaction and then send them to a IBM MQ. I am trying to deal with the error when there is no connection with IBM MQ to prevent transaction loss. In this case the jms template will throw an exception and the stream listener won't commit the transaction. The expected behavior is for the transaction to stay in the Kafka topic and for the stream listener to read it again. However the message seems to be consumed only once and there is no "rollback" taking place. To do so here are my configs :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              auto-commit-offset: false
      bindings:
        input:
          destination:  kafka_topic
          brokers: localhost:9092
```

And here is the code :

```
    public void handleMessage(Message<TransactionMessage> request,  @Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        TransactionMessage message = request.getPayload();
        System.out.println("Consumed a message");
        try {
            executionFlow.execute(message); // here the jmsTemplate throws an exception
            System.out.println("doing the ack");
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("did not send to MQ");
        }
    }
```

The code of the jmsTemplate which is called by the executionFlow :

```
    public void sendMessage(String messageTarget) {

        System.out.println("i am trying to send to MQ");
        try {
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationTopicQueue, messageTarget);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("jmsTemplate failed to send to IBM MQ");
        }
    }
```

Here is the output when I close the connection to IBM MQ:

```
Consumed a message
i am trying to send to MQ
did not send to MQ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("did not send to MQ");
    }
```

You need to re-throw the exception to cause a rollback.

You also need to enable Kafka transactions in the binder.

See [Kafka Binder Properties](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_binder_properties).

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix
```

> Enables transactions in the binder. See transaction.id in the Kafka documentation and Transactions in the spring-kafka documentation. When transactions are enabled, individual producer properties are ignored and all producers use the spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.* properties.
>
> Default null (no transactions)

If you also send data to kafka, you need a transactional producer

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.*
```

> Global producer properties for producers in a transactional binder. See spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix and Kafka Producer Properties and the general producer properties supported by all binders.
>
> Default: See individual producer properties.

Comment: I am not trying to write to a Kafka topic. Only to read from one and redirect the message to a IBM MQ. So not sure what it has to do with kafka producer configs ?

Comment: If you are not writing to kafka you don't need the producer part; I added that for others who might come across this question/answer in future.

Comment: If you are using Spring Cloud Stream 2.1 or higher, an alternative to enabling transactions in the binder is to add a custom `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean to the application and use it to set a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` on the listener container. That will have the same effect without the overhead of a kafka transaction. You still need to throw the exception so that it will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks. I was also able to configure the rollback with a Retry Template.